# Some Case statement issue

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I have two tables that has data like

table1

```
Id  id_nm
1   per
2   per
3   org
```

table2

```
Id Lst_id l_nm  up_dt
1   22    abc   9/10/2015
1   21    abs   10/12/2016
2   21    xzc   10/12/2013
2   23    xyz   10/21/2013
2   23    xnh   01/12/2013
```

Need to pick the `l_nm` where `lst_id` is 22. If that is not present then we need to pick the `l_nm` with the most recent updated date.

```
Id lst_id lnm   up_dt
1   22    abc   9/10/2015
2   23    xyz   10/21/2013
```

can any one please help me in implementing it.

Comment: Please show us your stored procedure

Comment: Like for ID1 i have two entries in table2 to i have to populate only those values taht have lst_id as 22.
But for Id 2 i don't have lst_is as 22 so i have diplay data that has max up_dt.

and need to join the table1 with table 2 to get all the data.

I have tried it with creating different blocks also and its working.

But i want something that can be done in one block.

Comment: I don't have procedure.

Comment: The why did you tag your question with PL/SQL? That is used to write stored procedures

Comment: i have to create materialized view.

Comment: That is not done using PL/SQL

Comment: yes i know...but in PL/SQL also you will use the SQL right to write select statements..

Comment: So you _do_ want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to use row_number with a window clause to generate a custom sort order:

```
select id, lst_id, l_nm as lnm, up_dt
from (
  select id
        ,lst_id
        ,l_nm
        ,up_dt
        ,row_number()
         over (partition by id
               order by case when lst_id = 22 then 1 else 2 end
                       ,up_dt desc) as rn    
  from table2
) where rn = 1;
```

Comment: i have tried this but its not working as i want both.

Comment: `create or replace view test_mv (id, id_nm, lst_id, l_nm, up_dt) as
select vw.id, vw.t1b, vw.t2b, vw.l_nm, vw.up_dt from 
( select t1.id, t1.id_nm t1b, t2.id_nm t2b, t2.l_nm, t2.up_dt,
  row_number() over (partition by t2.id order by case when t2.lst_id = 22 then 1 else 2 end, t2.up_dt desc) rn
  from table1 t1, table2 t2
  where t1.id = t2.id
) vw where vw.rn = 1;
;`

Comment: @Jig232 what do you mean "not working"? What result did you get?